# How can I share unicode text via the invocation framework using QML and C++?

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

When I try sharing Unicode text on the BB10 Cascades framework, using the following code, all non-ASCII characters are converted to question marks at the invocation target, such as a BBM conversation or an email:

```
InvokeActionItem {
    title: qsTr("Share")
    id: shareCard

    query {
      mimeType: "text/plain"
    invokeActionId: "bb.action.SHARE"
    }

onTriggered: {
  data = getData();
    }
}

function getData(){

    return "¿Cómo están las cosas en el mundo hoy?";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To workaround this, create a helper function in C++ that converts QStrings to Utf8, and call this from within your QML / JavaScript functions:

in your app.h

```
Q_INVOKABLE
QString Utf8EncodeString(const QString &encodeString);
```

in your app.cpp

```
QString app::Utf8EncodeString(const QString &encodeString) {
return encodeString.toUtf8();
}
```

In the QML change the getData() function thusly:

```
function getData(){
    return app.Utf8EncodeString("¿Cómo están las cosas en el mundo hoy?");
}
```